# How to create basic neural network in Python/Pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, pygame, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to understand how to create a basic, simple neural network in Python/Pygame. I have read [this](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html) tutorial and my aim is to create a program similar to the program that is described in "AI junkie". Although this tutorial is pretty simple. I still don't fully get it, and I am not sure about the connection between the output of the neurons to the movement of the tanks. Where can I find a simple, basic code of a program like this written in pygame/python, to try improving my understanding of the implementation of the algorithm?

Thanking you in anticipation!

Comment: I found one example: http://www.pygame.org/project-Smartsweeper-1492-.html

Comment: Thank you. I know this program, but I am looking for something more similar to the program in the link I attached.

Answer (score 1):

Check @Nathan's Python code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276933/good-open-source-neural-network-python-library/3143318#3143318) post. It's pretty clean and also good to take as a start point.

If you want logistic activation:

```
def logistic(x):
    return 1/(1+math.exp(-x))

# derivative of logistic
def dlogistic(y):
    return y*(1-y)
```

The default activation function is `tanh` in the original code.

It's quite straightforward to construct a network and start training:

```
# create a network with 5 inputs, 20 hiddens, and one output nodes
n = NN(5, 20, 1)
```